# Storing usage data about iOS app against the app store guidelines?

Tags: ios, app-store

What I would like to know is whether there is anything wrong (in terms of the law, and App Store guidelines) with storing information about your application, and broadcasting it to an online location for gathering.

Specifically, an application which would normally not connect to the internet, connecting when it starts up and storing usage information like time of day, the device ID, and how long the person uses it for.

I'm guessing this sort of behavior is fine so long as you get the users consent first?

Answer (score 0):

It’s fine if you ask the user first and give him an option to turn this feature off. We were once spanked out of the App Store simply for uploading a new game high-score record without a cancel button. It’s quite a long time and the rules might have changed, but better safe then sorry and your users will like the confirmation screen, too.